# Improving jQuery for many corresponding divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm still relatively new to jQuery and learning, I've created the below code/script that does what I need but I have to create a new function for every selector and target I add and the code will get long in the end as I intend to have at least 10 selectors and targets.

So when you hover over a selector (button) it adds an active class to that button (removing it from other buttons) and stays on till you select another button while at the same time switching out targets (different img's in this case).

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
body {
    background:grey;
}
#terrace-fw-wrap {
    display:block; 
    width:100%;
    max-width:600px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#terrace-fw-wrap .content {
    display:block; 
    width:100%;
}

#terrace-fw-wrap .content .img {
    display:none; 
    width:100%;
}

.active-img {
    display:block !important; 
    width:100% !important;
}

#terrace-fw-wrap .buttons .but {
    display:inline-block; 
    width:150px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    text-align: center;
    color:black;
    background:white;

}

#terrace-fw-wrap .buttons .but:hover {
    color:white;
    background:black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.active-but {
    color:white !important;
    background:black !important;

}

</style>

<section id="terrace-fw-wrap">
    <section class="content">
        <img class="img img1 active-img" src="http://s9.postimg.org/oatcz7bpr/img1.jpg" />
        <img class="img img2" src="http://s9.postimg.org/6314c1xxr/img2.jpg" />
        <img class="img img3" src="http://s30.postimg.org/llqz7e7yp/img3.jpg" />
    </section>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="but but1">
            Button 1
        </div>
        <div class="but but2">
            Button 2
        </div>
        <div class="but but3">
            Button 3
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<script>
$(function(){
    $('.but1').hover(function(){
      $('.img1').addClass('active-img');
      $('.img2').removeClass('active-img');
      $('.img3').removeClass('active-img');
      $('.but1').addClass('active-but');
      $('.but2').removeClass('active-but');
      $('.but3').removeClass('active-but');
    });        
});

$(function(){
    $('.but2').hover(function(){
      $('.img2').addClass('active-img');
      $('.img1').removeClass('active-img');
      $('.img3').removeClass('active-img');
      $('.but2').addClass('active-but');
      $('.but1').removeClass('active-but');
      $('.but3').removeClass('active-but');
    });        
});

$(function(){
    $('.but3').hover(function(){
      $('.img3').addClass('active-img');
      $('.img1').removeClass('active-img');
      $('.img2').removeClass('active-img');
      $('.but3').addClass('active-but');
      $('.but1').removeClass('active-but');
      $('.but2').removeClass('active-but');
    });        
});
</script>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8btdeftu/

Is there a way to change it so I can just add as many corresponding selectors and targets without having to add a new function to the script?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8btdeftu/1/).

Comment: Sorry @Huelfe, looking  that seems to break the functionality I need as the hovered button doesn't stay active and it doesn't switch out the images depending on which one you hover over, thanks for the try though.

Comment: sry my mistake. i've updated my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8btdeftu/6/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Changes Made**

HTML

► Added `data-img=""` to all buttons with corresponding images to be shown

**Solution**

```
$(function(){
    $('.but1,.but2,.but3').hover(function(){
        $('.img').removeClass('active-img');
        var img = $(this).data('img')
        $("."+img).addClass('active-img');
        $('.but').removeClass('active-but');
        $(this).addClass('active-but');
    });        
});
```

**[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/8btdeftu/3/)**

Comment: @Akshay Thank you `:)`

Comment: This is great, I looked at it and made one quick change removing the but1, but2, but3 etc classes and it seems to work now so now I just need to add a unique img# class to the <img> and each button just needs the unique data-img="" see the updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8btdeftu/5/. But yes yours is great optimised code thanks :)

Comment: `:)` Only one way for that. `Read lots of code ,write lots of code, read lots about code`

Comment: It's so hard to say a specific one is the definitive answer as there are a few great examples, but yes I've marked yours as the answer.

Comment: @Chobbit `:)`So true. Sometimes it is like that.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this Javascript, you can add as many buttons and images as you want as long as you add `data-image="imageID"` to the button and give the `<img>` an ID to link the two.

Using `$(this)` reflects to the button that just has been hovered on.

```
$('.but').hover(function() {
    $('.but').removeClass('active-but');
    $(this).addClass('active-but');
    $('img').removeClass('active-img');
    $('#'+ $(this).attr('data-image')).addClass('active-img');
});
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8btdeftu/4/)

Comment: @RinoRaj This code doesn't require to change the selectors. Your code still requires to define the 3 buttons as I use 1 class in this case which doesn't require any change in the Javascript code.

Comment: @RinoRaj & Jasper Vergers - To be honest both codes are great just slightly different but work, it's good to see and have alternative options. both get +1's from me.

Comment: To be honest this could be classed as the answer too and should certainly be concidered, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please use this code, it will work definitely.

```
$(function(){
$('.but').hover(function(){
var cls = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
var str = cls.slice(3);
$('.img').removeClass('active-img');
$('.but').removeClass('active-but');
$('.img'+str).addClass('active-img');
$('.but'+str).addClass('active-but');
});        
});
```

Comment: Thanks, This one works with my exact original HTML and you can just add more selectors and targets in the HTML, as can be seen in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8btdeftu/8/. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `toggleClass`.

Here is the HTML and JS for this solution:

```
<section id="terrace-fw-wrap">
    <section class="content">
        <img class="img img1 active-img" src="http://s9.postimg.org/oatcz7bpr/img1.jpg" />
        <img class="img img2" src="http://s9.postimg.org/6314c1xxr/img2.jpg" />
        <img class="img img3" src="http://s30.postimg.org/llqz7e7yp/img3.jpg" />
    </section>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="but but1" data-img="img1">
            Button 1
        </div>
        <div class="but but2" data-img="img2">
            Button 2
        </div>
        <div class="but but3" data-img="img3">
            Button 3
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".but").hover(function(){
        $(".but").removeClass("active-but");
        $(this).toggleClass("active-but");

        var imgSelector = "." + $(this).data("img");
        $(".img").removeClass("active-img");
        $(imgSelector).toggleClass("active-img");
    });
});
</script>
```